# MinGW compile fail : no such file or directory for a header file I created

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I began learning MinGW to compile C++ program. I had a sample C++ file including test.cpp (main program) and srfft.h (extra header file I added, not from the libray). The process executed as below step:

**g++ test.cpp -o test.exe**

**test.exe**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<< "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I got the correct answer, but when I added #include  in the C++ code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <srfft.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<< "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

CMD showed me" fatal error: srfft.h:No such file or directory"

How do I execute my code with MinGW? 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
#include "srfft.h"
```

Notice `""` instead of `<` and `>`. With `"srfft.h"`, the file is searched relative to the current directory, whereas with `<srfft.h>` the search only takes place in the system and specified include directories, which normally doesn't include the current directory.